# Will paypal cancel payment when in 'created' state for longer time?

Tags: php, api, paypal

I'm implementing PayPal payment method.

Let's have this situation:
- customer confirm order on my e-shop. After I recieve order confirmation (he submitted order-confirmation form), I create a new payment (via REST API and Paypal's PHP SDK, but it doesn't matter, payment method "paypal") and since now, the payment is in state 'created'. Then user is redirected to payment's approval link - so he can log in and approve payment for his order. But in this moment, he closes his browser or connection breaks up, etc. So he did not approve or cancel payment - so if I get payment through REST API, it is still in 'created' state.

I could not find any specific information about Paypal's payment state machine and it's restrictions/conditions (transitions of order from one state to another) - only some forum posts.

**What I am asking for is whether Paypal will automatically move payment to another state (failed/canceled/expired) after certain time (what time?) since payment was created, but not approved?** (I found some information that there is 3-hour period? But not from official source.)

Thanks!

Comment: Correct, it can be between 1 and 3 hours, it's more the token expiry limit which can be changed in your account I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in the case of the connection breaks or user closes the browser or any other case that breaks the flow, your system should always initiate a new payment if the customer comes back to repay.

The status will not be changing to another state. After 3 hours, the payment simply deletes itself and you won't be able to get it back to execute the payment, you will get an error.